# Spring MVC application.properties not override by profile file application-dev.properties

Tags: spring-mvc, properties, overriding, profile

I was looking at a way to configure different application.properties file depending on a JVM environnement variable.

I found this documentation on Spring references.

> In addition to application.properties files, profile-specific properties can also be defined using the naming convention application-{profile}.properties.
>
> Profile specific properties are loaded from the same locations as standard application.properties, with profile-specific files always overriding the default ones irrespective of whether the profile-specific files are inside or outside your packaged jar.

Then I did that :

[Configuration structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUz3h.png)

And then added a `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` to my JVM options.

[Profile option for JVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEfHk.png)

I tried to see that my params in dev are used but it isn't the case. Te application loads the data from the `application.properties` file.

Any idea why?

Comment: was this solved? I am facing the exact same issue.

Comment: No I changed my tactic and couldn't figure it out. Sorry bro.

Answer (score 3):

Try to modify the default properties file's name to 'application-default.properties', as it is said in the documentation:

> The Environment has a set of default profiles (by default [default]) which are used if no active profiles are set (i.e. if no profiles are explicitly activated then properties from application-default.properties are loaded).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties